# BIM360 Issues SortBy()

Tags: sorting, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

So I'm adapting this [example](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/bim360-csharp-issues) from forge.

I can currently retrieve all issues through a panel, I'm trying to sort the multiple issues by a attribute such as due date. I've tried a few different sortBy() methods but unsure how to get it to work.

Any ideas? here's the code below, where do I input the sortBy method?

```
BIM360IssueExtension.prototype.showIssues = function () {
  var _this = this;

  //remove the list of last time
  var pushPinExtension = _this.viewer.getExtension(_this.pushPinExtensionName);
  pushPinExtension.removeAllItems();
    pushPinExtension.showAll();
  var selected = getSelectedNode();

  _this.issues.forEach(function (issue) {
    var dateCreated = moment(issue.attributes.created_at);

    // show issue on panel
      if (_this.panel) {
        _this.panel.addProperty('Title', issue.attributes.title, 'Issue ' + issue.attributes.identifier);
        _this.panel.addProperty('Assigned to', issue.attributes.assigned_to, 'Issue ' + issue.attributes.identifier);
      //_this.panel.addProperty('Location', stringOrEmpty(issue.attributes.location_description), 'Issue ' + issue.attributes.identifier);
        _this.panel.addProperty('Version', 'V' + issue.attributes.starting_version + (selected.version != issue.attributes.starting_version ? ' (Not current)' : ''), 'Issue ' + issue.attributes.identifier)
        _this.panel.addProperty('Due Date', issue.attributes.due_date, 'Issue ' + issue.attributes.identifier);
      _this.panel.addProperty('Created at', dateCreated.format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a'), 'Issue ' + issue.attributes.identifier);
    }

    // add the pushpin
    var issueAttributes = issue.attributes;
    var pushpinAttributes = issue.attributes.pushpin_attributes;
    if (pushpinAttributes) {
      issue.type = issue.type.replace('quality_', ''); // temp fix during issues > quality_issues migration
      pushPinExtension.createItem({
        id: issue.id,
        label: issueAttributes.identifier,
        status: issue.type && issueAttributes.status.indexOf(issue.type) === -1 ? `${issue.type}-${issueAttributes.status}` : issueAttributes.status,
        position: pushpinAttributes.location,
        type: issue.type,
        objectId: pushpinAttributes.object_id,
        viewerState: pushpinAttributes.viewer_state
      });
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll need some library to sort, something like [Underscore](https://underscorejs.org/#sortBy). You can simply use their CDN:

```
<script src="https://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Then, after loading the `Issues` and before listing them (e.g. [this line at the sample](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/bim360-csharp-issues/blob/master/bim360issues/wwwroot/js/BIM360IssueExtension.js#L270)), try something like:

```
// sort by title
_this.issues = _.sortBy(_this.issues, function (i){return i.attributes.title});

// or sort by due date (this Date.parse returns an int representing the date)
_this.issues = _.sortBy(_this.issues, function (i){return Date.parse(i.attributes.due_date)});
```

BTW, you'll need to handle the case where the `due_date` is not specified (null)

Comment: I have tried inputting this but it doesn't have any affect on the outcome, I have tried it in multiple different positions of the code?

Comment: I have edited my answer with a link to where to place it

Comment: When I do this, the issues extension doesn't load, just the normal viewer?

Comment: this is probably due to some syntax error... anything on the console? (i tried the code, works fine)

Comment: Sorry, I was only trying the date sortby, the title sortby works, the date one doesn't, it now shows the extension, just doesn't sort the issues

Comment: you probably need to ensure the `due_date` is valid or add an `if` check on the code... :) let me know if you have other question and please mark this as answered when done, thanks

Comment: I have various different valid due_date's, also the title code doesn't work if I use a different attribute apart from title

Comment: I'm unsure why the code only works with the title attribute

Comment: it's probably because only title is always there, other attributes may be empty... so you need add some check before sorting (depending on the attribute type)